# Problem with Serial communication RXTX and Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, serial-communication, rxtx, ftdi

I am having this problem below:

**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F1joXc9xppFWRRqxWaaC7izRNaSnVaYc/view?usp=sharing**

I already searched this problem here and in other foruns, and it seems to be a quite frequent problem, although I still cannot solve it. The arduino is the **Pro Mini** and it is connected to a **FTDI adapter**

1- The communication is working perfectly;

2- The baud-rate is the same in the script and in the seriel monitor (as you can see in the image above);

3- I already uninstall the Java and install it again, but still giving me the same problem in the Arduino IDE serial monitor;

4- I'm quite sure that the problem is related with the Java/Arduino serial communication, something related with **RXTX communication** and **Arduino**... Maybe I must use PuTTY but I do not know if it is a good solution. I do not know what to do...

*Have you ever had this problem before?
What do you think I can do?*

Comment: Please don't link your problem to a 3rd party site.  Many are blocked from viewing such content (as I am).

Comment: Are you sure you have chosen the correct COM port in the Serial Monitor? Try changing the cable between arduino and the serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I already know what the problems was!

I selected the wrong processor definitions: 
**ATMEGA328 (5V, 16MHz)** instead of **ATMEGA328 (3.3V, 8MHz)** ...